# Child Objects In PHP

Tags: php

How would I make it so that I can have a heirarchy of classes and objects that works like this:

```
 class App {
//App code
}

class Balances extends App {

  public function test() {
    echo 'test';
  }

}

$app = new App();
$app->Balances->test();
```

Comment: You need to have a property inside `App` that has an object `Balances`. You are currently extending the `App` class,

Comment: @MehdiBounya Could you give an example of what this would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do so with your current code.

`extends` creates a class and inherit the methods and properties of the other class. (Currently `Balances` inherit from `App`).

Check [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.extends) for more details.

You can do it like this:

```
class Balances {
    public function foo(){
        echo "I'm foo in Balances";
    }
}

class App{
    public $Balances;

    public function __construct(){
        // Create an instance of the class Balances and assign it to the property Balances
        $this->Balances = new Balances();
    }
}

$app = new App();

$app->Balances->foo(); // Gives: I'm foo in Balances
```